# Read structured ascii files into python data structure for interpolation analysis

Tags: python, arrays

I have about 50 files. A parameter (let's call it x) is built into the file name as a sort of tag. Something like `data_0.100.txt` to give `x=0.100`. Each file has about 100k lines. A line is structured as 'string float float float'. The idea is to read all files content into an array with 'x' and the 'string' as keys and the floats as content. Something like `val(x,<string>)= [float, float, float]`

We then need to perform an interpolation check on the data where we use data from every 5th x-value as reference points to construct an interpolated function. The Python array slicing capability would be a good way to do that. I have already decided to use `interp1d` for the interpolation. Then we loop through all the other x-values and compare the float value against the evaluate interpolation function. Something like `delta(x)= val(x) - inter(x)` (for a given 'string'). Then some work on the deltas like summing them all up or finding the worst in either direction or plotting them nicely.

I want to start by designing the data structure and Python has many ways to do it. Should one use array, hash, numpy-array etc for the purpose? What offers the easiest data-reading option? What the easiest/fastest processing?

There will probably be many follow-up questions.

Comment: For reading the file I think you can use `numpy.genfromtxt` as you have only 4 columns. Something like `a,b,c,d = np.genfromtxt("/home/filename.txt",unpack=True)`
Use a `for` loop via `os.listdir` to get all your data from the folder